# Экспорт нескольких анимаций из 3d max в unity3d в формате fbx

Tags: unity3d, 3dsmax

Как экспортировать модель из 3dmax 2014 с несколькими слоями CAT анимаций, что бы при импорте в unity3d у персонажа были несколько анимаций а не одна?

Comment: Я использовал [следующю инструкцию, надеюсь поможет](http://docs.unity3d.ru/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectMax.html)

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам требуется просто использовать дополнительные файлы анимации, то добавляйте их через AddClip:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public AnimationClip walkClip;
    public Animation anim;
    void Start() {
        anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
        anim.AddClip(anim.clip, "shoot", 0, 10);
        anim.AddClip(anim.clip, "walk", 11, 20, true);
        anim.AddClip(anim.clip, "idle", 21, 30, true);
    }
}
```

Файлы анимаций импортируются из 3D MAX на голом скелете в файлы fbx и должны иметь название в формате: `имя@animation.fbx`